# Catalog Flat Category reindex issue

Tags: catalog, indexing

I am using magento 1.7. I came up with the following issue 'cannot create table column without comments'.I have attached the log

```
2013-07-26T08:33:24+00:00 DEBUG (7): Exception message: Cannot create table without columns comments
Trace: #0 D:\xampp\htdocs\munch4me\app\code\core
\Mage\Catalog\Model\Resource\Category\Flat.php(604): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->         createTable(Object(Varien_Db_Ddl_Table))
#1 app\code\core\Mage\Catalog\Model\Resource\Category\Flat.php(1418): Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Category_Flat->_createTable('1')
#2 app\code\core\Mage\Catalog\Model\Resource\Category\Flat.php(1431): Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Category_Flat->_createTables()
#3 app\code\core\Mage\Catalog\Model\Category\Indexer\Flat.php(246): Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Category_Flat->reindexAll()
#4 app\code\core\Mage\Index\Model\Process.php(209): Mage_Catalog_Model_Category_Indexer_Flat->reindexAll()
#5 app\code\core\Mage\Index\Model\Process.php(255): Mage_Index_Model_Process->reindexAll()
#6 app\code\core\Mage\Index\controllers\Adminhtml\ProcessController.php(124): Mage_Index_Model_Process->reindexEverything()
#7 app\code\core\Mage\Core\Controller\Varien\Action.php(419):    Mage_Index_Adminhtml_ProcessController->reindexProcessAction()
#8 app\code\core\Mage\Core\Controller\Varien\Router\Standard.php(250): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('reindexProcess')
#9 app\code\core\Mage\Core\Controller\Varien\Front.php(176):  Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#10 app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#11 app\Mage.php(683): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#12 index.php(87): Mage::run('', 'store')
#13 {main}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**General info**
In the DDL creation of tables Magento does not allow (for some reason still unknown to me) the creation of columns without a comment.
**Specific info**
The flat category tables are creating by adding one column for each column in the `catalog_category_entity` table and one column for each category attribute.
All columns from `catalog_category_entity` are retrieved by this method `Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Category_Flat::_getStaticColumns` but I doubt the problem is in there, because, when retrieving these columns, the comment for the column is the same as the column name. (`'comment' => $column['COLUMN_NAME']`)
So most probably the issue is with one of the attributes.
The attribute columns are generated in `Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Category_Flat::_getEavColumns()` and the comment for the column is the `frontend_label` of the attribute.
**In conclusion** most probably you have (at least) one category attribute that has a null value for the frontend label.
You can identify the attribute(s) by running this query on your database:

```
SELECT e.* 
FROM  
    eav_attribute e
LEFT JOIN  eav_entity_type et 
   ON e.entity_type_id = et.entity_type_id
WHERE 
   et.entity_type_code =  'catalog_category' AND 
   e.frontend_label IS NULL
```

If you find one, just add a frontend label (or make it an empty string) and it should work. The only constraint is that it shouldn't be `NULL`.

**[EDIT]**
You can debug this issue but adding this piece of code:
echo "

```
"; print_r($columnEntry);exit; 
inside the method Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql::createTable() right before the exception is thrown.
```

`if (empty($columnEntry['COMMENT'])) {
    echo "<pre>"; print_r($columnEntry);exit; //add this heare
    throw new Zend_Db_Exception("Cannot create table without columns comments");
}`

Now, instead of the exception you should see how the `$columnEntry` looks like and get an idea on what is the problematic attribute.

Comment: @Mariues , I ran the query above and added the frontend label for those attributes but still no luck,it still throws same exception

Comment: I've edited the answer and added some pointers on how you can debug the issue.

Comment: Thank you , the problem is solved, I found some of the values for frontend label was zero